# How to Insert an array of JSON objects into a MongoDB collection together with a Job ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb

I have an array of JSON objects that looks similar to the below structure:

```
let myContacts =
    [  
       {  
          "name":"Tom Smith",
          "address":"111 qwerty street",
          "notes":"tom"
       },
       {  
          "name":"Sam Smith",
          "address":"222 qwerty street",
          "notes":"sam"
       },
       {  
          "name":"Sally Smith",
          "address":"333 qwerty street",
          "notes":"sally"
       }
    ]
```

What I would like to achieve is the ability to insert the whole array into a MongoDB collection called "contacts" together with an associated job id for the whole insert transaction.

So within my "contacts" collection, I would see the following documents with the added jodid of 1.

On my next insert of the array of objects, I would then use `"jobid":2` and so forth.

Here jobid is a number where I have a separate collection that holds this value and is incremented each time an insert transaction is performed of the array.

```
   {  
      "_id": "rg8nsoqsxhpNYho2N",
      "jobid": 1,
      "name":"Tom Smith",
      "address":"111 qwerty street",
      "notes":"tom"
   },
   {  
      "_id": "yKMx6sHQboL5m8Lqx",
      "jobid": 1,
      "name":"Sam Smith",
      "address":"222 qwerty street",
      "notes":"sam"
   },
   {  
      "_id": "xwex6sHQboL3m3L3a",
      "jobid": 1,
      "name":"Sally Smith",
      "address":"333 qwerty street",
      "notes":"sally"
   }
```

Next run would then look like:

```
   {  
      "_id": "rg9nsserhpNYho1I",
      "jobid": 2,
      "name":"Tom Smith",
      "address":"111 qwerty street",
      "notes":"tom"
   },
   {  
      "_id": "aKWx4sHQboL5m8Lw",
      "jobid": 2,
      "name":"Sam Smith",
      "address":"222 qwerty street",
      "notes":"sam"
   },
   {  
      "_id": "rwex22HQboL3m3P2l",
      "jobid": 2,
      "name":"Sally Smith",
      "address":"333 qwerty street",
      "notes":"sally"
   }
```

Using JavaScript, what would be the best and fastest approach to perform the above?

Within the MongoDB manual online, I see examples like:

```
myContacts.forEach((contact) => db.contacts.insert(contact));
```

Another example is:

```
db.contacts.insertMany(myContacts)
```

but unsure how to include jobid in the above examples.

Comment: Does jobid have to be numerically increasing? If yes it will be fun to sync that in a large database.

Comment: Oh wait, just wondering, is jobID incremental for every object?

Comment: I have updated my question to clear up jobid queries.

Comment: Turns out I have greatly misunderstood your question

Comment: Obtaining the `jobid` is not my issue it's how do I best insert the array of objects into my contacts mongo collection.